# Windows Kernel: patching code in OS modules

Tags: kernel, driver, kernel-module, windows-kernel

Environment:

1. Windows 8.1 (x64)
2. Visual Studio
3. WinDbg

Upon driver start-up, I need to change a single byte of bthport.sys to change it's run-time behavior, I am able to find the exact place to be updated, unfortunately, when updating the instruction I get GeneralProtection faliure, setting up the WP flag of the CR0 register didn't help.

How can I programmatically control page protection in a kernel mode driver ?

Comment: Windows features PatchGuard today, a countermeasure against malware doing this.  And you.  Surely you knew this was going to byte you in the rear end some day.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify code without changing page protection. It depends where you need to change this byte. For some drivers it's happened that IRP Major and IRP Minor callbacks saved in .DATA section. If the code is inside this callbacks you can replace them with you own code(be aware about global which they used).

Answer (score 0):

Check "Windows 8 Kernel Memory Protections Bypass" at: https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/2014/08/15/windows-8-kernel-memory-protections-bypass/